# Counting like elements in a list and appending list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am trying to create a `list` in `Python` with values pulled from an active `excel` sheet. I want it to pull the step # value from the excel file and append it to the list while also including which number of that element it is. For example, `1_1` the first time it pulls 1, `1_2` the second time, `1_3` the third, etc. My code is as follows...

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
CellNum = xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Steps = []
for i in range(2,CellNum + 1):  #Create load and step arrays in abaqus after importing from excel
if str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6') in Steps:
    StepCount = 1
    for x in Steps:
        if x == str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6'):
            StepCount+=1
    Steps.append(str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+'_'+str(StepCount))
else:
    Steps.append(str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+'_1')
```

I understand that without the excel file, the program will not run for any of you, but I was just wondering if it is some simple error that I am missing. When I run this, the StepCount does not go higher than 2 so I receive a bunch of 1_2, 2_2, 3_2, etc elements. I've posted my resulting list below.

```
>>> Steps
['1_1', '2_1', '3_1', '4_1', '5_1', '6_1', '7_1', '8_1', '9_1', '10_1', '11_1', '12_1',
 '13_1', '14_1', '1_2', '14_2', '13_2', '12_2', '11_2', '10_2', '2_2', '3_2', '9_2',
 '8_2', '7_2', '6_2', '5_2', '4_2', '3_2', '2_2', '1_2', '2_2', '3_2', '4_2', '5_2', 
'6_2', '7_2', '8_2', '9_2', '10_2', '11_2', '12_2', '13_2', '14_2', '1_2', '2_2']
```

**EDIT #1:** So, if the `('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6')` will ALWAYS only use _1, is it this line of code that is messing with my counter?

```
if x == str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6'):
```

Since it is only using `_1`, it will only count `1_1` and not check `1_2, 1_3, 1_4, etc`

**EDIT #2:** Now I am using the following code. My input list is also below.

```
from collections import defaultdict
StepsList = []
Steps = []
tracker = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(2,CellNum + 1):
    StepsList.append(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))

>>> StepsList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 2, 3, 9, 8,
 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 2]

for cell in StepsList:
    Steps.append('{}_{}'.format(cell, tracker[cell]+1)) # This is +1 because the     tracker starts at 0
    tracker[cell]+=1
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: zero length field name in format` from the `for cell in StepsList:` iteration block

**EDIT #3:** Got it working. For some reason it didn't like

```
Steps.append('{}_{}'.format(cell, tracker[cell]+1))
```

So I just changed it to

```
for cell in StepsList:
    tracker[cell]+=1
    Steps.append(str(cell)+'_'+str(tracker[cell]))
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if str(int(xl.Cells(i,1).value))+('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6') in Steps:
```

does not do what you think it does. `('_1' or '_2' or '_3' or '_4' or '_5' or '_6')` will *always* return `'_1'`. It does not iterate over that series of `or` values looking for a match.

Without seeing expected input vs. expected output, it's hard to point you in the correct direction to actually get what you want out of your code, but likely you'll want to leverage [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or one of the other combinatoric methods from `itertools`.

**Update**

Based on your comments, I think that this is a way of solving your problem. Assuming an input list of the following:

```
in_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

You can do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tracker = defaultdict(int) # defaultdict is just a regular dict with a default value at new keys (in this case 0)
steps   = []

for cell in in_list:
    steps.append('{}_{}'.format(cell, tracker[cell]+1)) # This is +1 because the tracker starts at 0
    tracker[cell]+=1
```

Result:

```
 >>> steps
 ['1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '2_1', '3_1', '3_2', '4_1']
```

There are likely more efficient ways to do this using combinations of `itertools`, but this way is certainly the most straight-forward

Comment: Okay, but if 1_1 is in the list, it should then set StepCount=1 and iterate through the list elements to count each time 1_1, 1_2, 1_3 appears, no? My problem, it seems, is that the StepCount is either only recognizing 1 of the elements during iteration, or the StepCount keeps getting reset back to 1. The former seems more likely, but I don't understand why. I am a beginner at Python.

Comment: No, you'll get 1_1 the first time through because the list doesn't contain a ``1_1``, then ``1_2`` because ``1_1`` is already in the list, and then never again. The only element you're ever searching for is ``X_1``.

Comment: Sorry, I explained that poorly. You basically have the same mistake inside the condition from your first mistake. So basically, it's only ever looking for ``X_1``, and as soon as it finds it it adds ``X_2`` and then boots out.

Comment: I am just going to edit my original post since it is easier to reference code there